# Windows 8 driver setup error on a Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-8

I have Hyper-v Windows 2008 R2 sp1 x64, and I downloaded Windows 8 Pro x64 to test the OS and fool around with it. When I try to install from the ISO or the DVD I get a windows Setup error:

> A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could be a DVD,
>   USB or Hard disk driver. ..."

[image]

I have installed Win7 images on the same host.
Help?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to create a VHD file for the VM?

Comment: Well, I think i did... a couple times. Even did another win7. Win8 still no. I am gonna redownload the release... both 64 & 32 and try tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISO filesize of Win8 download was not correct. There were no errors mounting the ISO nor burning the ISO to a dvd. I re-downloaded the ISO and the install went fine.

Comment: I was able to figure out my downloaded file was incorrect by calculating its MD5 checksum, probably a more reliable way of verifying the integrity of the file instead of checking its size.